# Lenovo e495 Ryzen 7 3700U - manual fan control - rpm speed for level 1

Tags: lenovo, overheating, fan, temperature

According to specification Ryzen 7 3700U can survive without problems up to 105C. However the system turns on the fan when the temperature is slightly higher than 40C and instead of puting fan to work very slowly, it sets 3300 RPM which means that you can easily hear laptop sound. At such a temperature I would rather expect to have fan around 2000 RPM and it would make it almost silent. There is no any performance option in Bios. Reducing TDP with RyzenAdj helps a bit but not too much.

I spent a lot of time on some investigation using fan control tutorials (ex. this one https://www.dobreprogramy.pl/Red_Shoehart/Konfiguracja-ThinkFan-w-Lenovo-Ts,100188.html it's in Polish but you can easily guess what has been done basing on commands).

I succeeded controlling fan but it didn't solve my problem. Why?

I'm guessing that the reason of problems with noisy fan is the following:

Linux doesn't control directly fan in RPM but using levels 0-7. EC firmware controls what RPM corresponds to which level. Unfortunately EC firmware for e495 sets 3300 RPM as level 1 thus the lowest however 3300RPM is too much and it makes system quite noisy. I'm guessing that for level 1 around 2000 RPM would be fully enough. It can be easily checked by setting fan manually to level 1 by:

```
echo level 1 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
```

If anyone has any other suggestions, that would be welcome. Otherwise we can only hope that Lenovo will modify fan control during next EC firmware to set lower rpm values for level 1 and also probably level 2.

Question 1: Do you know any way to control RPMs directly from Linux (not using default EC firmware levels?

By the way I noticed that thinkfan works a bit strange with many spikes. It turns on for 1-2, max. 4 seconds and it turns off. It's quite irritating. Comparing to default Lenovo settings, Lenovo has much longer working/not working periods.

To give you few examples:

[image]

[image]

I tried with two different profiles in /etc/thinkfan.conf control:

```
(0, 0,  60)
(1, 48, 65)
(2, 55, 68)
(3, 57, 70)
(4, 61, 72)
(5, 67, 73)
(7, 70, 32767)

(0, 0,  60)
(1, 53, 65)
(2, 55, 66)
(3, 57, 68)
(4, 61, 70)
(5, 64, 71)
(7, 68, 32767)
```

But both cause these short lasting spikes.

Moreover there is strange thing with sensor detecting. I've checked two cases. One with using default sensors, second with using sensors found by:

```
find /sys/devices -type f -name "temp*_input"
```

In the second case after running fan control I have the following error:

[image]

Moreover after this the thinkfanl exited with fully turning off any fan control. I reached almost 80C for short time (for processor) thus much higher temperature and fan was not turned on. Which means if I countinue I would "fry" my computer.

Just for comparison default Lenovo profile (without spikes):

[image]

Question 2: How to configure thinkfan to avoid these spikes and to have long periods of the same fan speed?

In results of many hours of play, I've returned to Lenovo default profile (thinkfan is not active), uppps....